# How to calculate averages of columns and remove some rows in R?

Tags: r

When I have a data frame like;

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5
R1  27  38  94  40  4
R2  69  16  85  2   15
R3  30  35  64  95  6
R4  20  33  77  98  55
R5  20  44  60  33  89
R6  12  88  87  44  38
```

and I want to calculate an average from Column C4 to C5. After that, I just want to keep rows that are higher than 50.

Since only row R4 and R5 meet the conditions, my final output should be:

```
    C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  Average C4:C5
R4  20  33  77  98  55       77
R5  20  44  60  33  89       61
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
subset(transform(df, Avg = (C4 + C5)/2), Avg > 50)

#   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5  Avg
#R3 30 35 64 95  6 50.5
#R4 20 33 77 98 55 76.5
#R5 20 44 60 33 89 61.0
```

Or in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Avg = (C4 + C5)/2) %>% filter(Avg > 50)
```

---

If there are lot of columns that you want to consider to calculate mean you can use `rowMeans`.

```
cols <- paste0('C', 4:5)
df$Avg <- rowMeans(df[cols])
subset(df, Avg > 50)
```